# Expected Data not appearing in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, arrays

I have this simple XML and is parsing it and passing its child data into another view controller, my XML is like this,

```
<categories>
  <category>
    <name>Electronics</name>
    <description>This is the given sample description of main menu</description>
    <image>Link Here</image>
    <sub_cat>
       <sub_name>Laptop</sub_name>
       <sub_desc>sub cat description of Laptop</sub_desc>
       <sub_image>Link Here</sub_image>
    </sub_cat>
    <sub_cat>
       <sub_name>Printers</sub_name>
       <sub_desc>sub cat description of Printers</sub_desc>
       <sub_image>Link Here</sub_image>
    </sub_cat>
  </category>
  <category>
    <name>Food</name>
    <description>This is the given sample description of main menu</description>
    <image>Link Here</image>
    <sub_cat>
        <sub_name>Pizza</sub_name>
        <sub_desc>sub cat description of pizza</sub_desc>
        <sub_image>Link Here</sub_image>
    </sub_cat>
    <sub_cat>
        <sub_name>Burgers</sub_name>
        <sub_desc>sub cat description of Burgers</sub_desc>
        <sub_image>Link Here</sub_image>
    </sub_cat>
  </category>
  <category>
     <name>Gifts</name>
     <description>This is the given sample description of main menu</description>
     <image>Link Here</image>
     <sub_cat>
          <sub_name>Photo Albums</sub_name>
          <sub_desc>sub cat description of Photo Album</sub_desc>
          <sub_image>Link Here</sub_image>
     </sub_cat>
     <sub_cat>
          <sub_name>Car</sub_name>
          <sub_desc>sub cat description of Car</sub_desc>
          <sub_image>Link Here</sub_image>
     </sub_cat>
   </category>
</categories>
```

And Im parsing this array using NSXMLParser as its a simple XML, and Im parsing it like this,

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"]){

        _mainCategory = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    } else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"sub_cat"]){
        _subCategory = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    currentData  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        [_mainCategory setValue:currentData forKey:elementName];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]){
        [_mainCategory setValue:currentData forKey:elementName];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        [_mainCategory setValue:currentData forKey:elementName];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"sub_name"]) {
        [_subCategory setValue:currentData forKey:elementName];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"sub_desc"]) {
        [_subCategory setValue:currentData forKey:elementName];

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"sub_cat"]) {
        [_childPopulated addObject:_subCategory];

    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"]){


        [_mainCategory setValue:_childPopulated forKey:@"sub_cat"];

        [_listPopulated addObject:_mainCategory];

        _mainCategory = nil;
        _childPopulated = nil;

    }


}
```

and my output data looks like this,

```
{
        description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
        image = "Link Here";
        name = Electronics;
        "sub_cat" =    (
                        {
                "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
                "sub_name" = Laptop;
            },
                        {
                "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
                "sub_name" = Printers;
            }
        );
    },
        {
        description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
        image = "Link Here";
        name = Food;
    },
        {
        description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
        image = "Link Here";
        name = Gifts;
    }
```

but my expected data should be like the first index in that array with the sub_cat as the key. But its not fetching the other sub_cat when it goes into the second sub category,

My Expected value should be like this,

```
 {
     description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
     image = "Link Here";
     name = Electronics;
     "sub_cat" =    (
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
                    "sub_name" = Laptop;
                },
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
                    "sub_name" = Printers;
                }
            );
     description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
     image = "Link Here";
     name = Food;
     "sub_cat" =    (
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
                    "sub_name" = Pizza;
                },
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
                    "sub_name" = Burger;
                }
            );
      description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
      image = "Link Here";
      name = Gift;
      "sub_cat" =    (
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
                    "sub_name" = Car;
                },
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
                    "sub_name" = Photo Album;
                }
            );
 }
```

I dont know what im missing in parsing this, just wanted to know if why is the rest of the sub categoryis not appearing .

Comment: Can you add the full xml so we can check that you really put in some sub_cats?

Comment: PLease check the updated XML and if u need the XML link here it is too, http://www.irabwah.com/product.xml

Comment: Please summarise the difference between your actual and expected results, so I don't have to run `diff` on it.

Comment: difference is that in my actual result only the first sub category of the first category only appears in the 2nd and 3rd category the sub categories doesn't appear. It doesn't show at all.

Comment: and btw, im making an array as the main category with dictionaries having there elementName as a key and an array of subcategory which is in the main category array, and the values of the sub category are dictionaries with the value as key. Hope this help. Would really like to know what im doing wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Expected value should be like this

```
{
    {
     description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
     image = "Link Here";
     name = Electronics;
     "sub_cat" =    (
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
                    "sub_name" = Laptop;
                },
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
                    "sub_name" = Printers;
                }
            );
},
   {  description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
     image = "Link Here";
     name = Food;
     "sub_cat" =    (
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
                    "sub_name" = Pizza;
                },
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
                    "sub_name" = Burger;
                }
            );
},
     { description = "This is the given sample description of main menu";
      image = "Link Here";
      name = Gift;
      "sub_cat" =    (
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
                    "sub_name" = Car;
                },
                            {
                    "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
                    "sub_name" = Photo Album;
                }
            );
}
 }
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I have implemented that already tho, now Im trying to do is used other parser to parse the data and show it like that, and also saving it into a data base or NSCache so reloading the table wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

You should probably use `-setObject:forKey:` to put objects in your dictionaries.  It's marginally faster than `-setValue:forKey:` and doesn't treat the keys in any special way.

Also, you never seem to allocate a mutable array for `_childPopulated`.  This might be the cause of your issue.